# CCRenderTexture anchorPoint or what?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, rendering

I need CCRenderTexture (white rect) to render my sprite here (1st picture), but its render only at the lower-left corner (2nd picture). How can I change this value?

[First picture](http://s29.postimg.org/pyzop7dmf/06_2014_23_37_21.png)

[Second Picture](http://s17.postimg.org/vvbgcyjy7/06_2014_23_37_31.png)

renderTextrure.position = ccp(p.x, p.y);

renderTexture.sprite.position = ccp(p.x, p.y);

renderTexture.sprite.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5, 0.5);

EDIT

[CCRenderTexture initial position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725181/ccrendertexture-initial-position?rq=1)

[CCRenderTexture size and position in Cocos2d-iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061940/ccrendertexture-size-and-position-in-cocos2d-iphone?rq=1)

I found these answers, but it didn't help. Is it possible to change this position or not?

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps you. Note that the UIImage is optional incase you want to use it as UIIMage.

```
    CCRenderTexture *renderer = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:tx height:ty            pixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888 depthStencilFormat:GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8];

     [renderer beginWithClear:0 g:0 b:0 a:0 depth:1.0f];
     [1st_pic_sprite visit];
     [renderer end];
     UIImage *img = [renderer getUIImage];
```